# Edit Form not showing the values in input fields

Tags: magento-1.9, forms, adminform, edit, input

I have a form that saved the value in DB and then i have retrieve that values in an admin Grid Now on Grid view i have Edit button that suppose to be take the user to edit form and after some changes save the edit form. But in my case it showing empty forms.

I have Controller function for edit action is as like follows:

```
public function editAction()

 {
     $this->_registryObject();
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('optfirst_reviewmycompany/adminhtml_edits_edit')
            ->toHtml()
    );

 }
```

Here is the Edit.php code

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->_blockGroup = 'optfirst_reviewmycompany';
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_edits';
    $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('Social Icons');
}
```

And this is my Edit action from my Grid:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_review';
    $this->_blockGroup = 'optfirst_reviewmycompany';
    $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('Social Icon Manager');
    $this->_addButton('add_new', array(
    'label'   => Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('Edit Social Icons'),
    'onclick' => "setLocation('{$this->getUrl('/adminform/edit')}')",
    'class'   => 'edit'
));
    parent::__construct();
}
```

And here is the form.php code that have to show the edit input fields:

```
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
        'id' => 'edit_form',
        'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/edit'),
        'method' => 'post',
        ));

    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);

    $helper = Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany');
    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('display', array('legend' => $helper->__('Select Social Icons'),
            'class' => 'fieldset-wide'));

    $fieldset->addField('google', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'google',
        'label' => $helper->__('Google'),
        ));
    $fieldset->addField('twitter', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'twitter',
        'label' => $helper->__('Twitter'),
        ));
    $fieldset->addField('yelp', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'yelp',
        'label' => $helper->__('Yelp'),
        ));
    $fieldset->addField('linkedin', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'linkedin',
        'label' => $helper->__('LinkedIn'),
        ));
     $fieldset->addField('pintrest', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'pintrest',
        'label' => $helper->__('Pintrest'),
        ));
     $fieldset->addField('gmaps', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'gmaps',
        'label' => $helper->__('Google Map'),
        ));
     $fieldset->addField('bing', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'bing',
        'label' => $helper->__('Bing'),
        ));
     $fieldset->addField('coc', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'coc',
        'label' => $helper->__('Chamber of Commerce'),
        ));
     $fieldset->addField('city_search', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'city_search',
        'label' => $helper->__('City Search'),
        ));
     $fieldset->addField('ezlocal', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'ezlocal',
        'label' => $helper->__('EZLocal'),
        ));
     $fieldset->addField('local', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'local',
        'label' => $helper->__('Local'),
        ));
     $fieldset->addField('mcircle', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'mcircle',
        'label' => $helper->__('MerchantCircle'),
        ));
     $fieldset->addField('show_me_local', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'show_me_local',
        'label' => $helper->__('ShowmeLocal'),
        ));
     $fieldset->addField('superpages', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'superpages',
        'label' => $helper->__('Superpages'),
        ));
     $fieldset->addField('topix', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'topix',
        'label' => $helper->__('Topix'),
        ));
     $fieldset->addField('uscity', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'uscity',
        'label' => $helper->__('USCity'),
        ));
     $fieldset->addField('where_to_app', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'where_to_app',
        'label' => $helper->__('Wheretoapp'),
        ));
     $fieldset->addField('yahoo', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'yahoo',
        'label' => $helper->__('Yahoo'),
        ));
     $fieldset->addField('yellow_bot', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'yellow_bot',
        'label' => $helper->__('Yellowbot'),
        ));
     $fieldset->addField('yellow_wise', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'yellow_wise',
        'label' => $helper->__('Yellowise'),
        ));


    if (Mage::registry('optfirst_reviewmycompany')) {
        $form->setValues(Mage::registry('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->getData());

    }

    return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

Registry form object

```
protected function _registryObject()
{

 $id=$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
 $data=Mage::getModel('optfirst_reviewmycompany/review')->load($id);
 Mage::register('optfirst_reviewmycompany', $data);
  }
```

Here is the Grid.php

```
<?php

  class OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Block_Adminhtml_Review_Grid extends
    Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
   {


public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('reviewGrid');
    $this->setDefaultSort('id_optfirst_reviewmycompany');
    $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
}

protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('optfirst_reviewmycompany/review')->getCollection();
    //print_r($collection);
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('facebook', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('Facebook'),
        'align' => 'right',
        'width' => '10px',
        'index' => 'facebook',
        ));

    $this->addColumn('google', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('Google'),
        'align' => 'left',
        'index' => 'google',
        'width' => '50px',
        ));


    $this->addColumn('linkedin', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('Linkedin'),
        'width' => '150px',
        'index' => 'linkedin',
        ));

    $this->addColumn('twitter', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('Linkedin'),
        'width' => '150px',
        'index' => 'twitter',
        ));

    $this->addColumn('yelp', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('Linkedin'),
        'width' => '150px',
        'index' => 'yelp',
        ));
    $this->addColumn('pintrest', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('Pintrest'),
        'width' => '150px',
        'index' => 'pintrest',
        ));

    $this->addColumn('gmaps', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('Google Maps'),
        'width' => '150px',
        'index' => 'gmaps',
        ));

    $this->addColumn('bing', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('Bing'),
        'width' => '150px',
        'index' => 'bing',
        ));
    $this->addColumn('coc', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('Chamber of Commerce'),
        'width' => '150px',
        'index' => 'coc',
        ));
    $this->addColumn('city_search', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('City Search'),
        'width' => '150px',
        'index' => 'city_search',
        ));
    $this->addColumn('ezlocal', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('EZLocal'),
        'width' => '150px',
        'index' => 'ezlocal',
        ));
    $this->addColumn('local', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('Local'),
        'width' => '150px',
        'index' => 'city_search',
        ));
    $this->addColumn('mcircle', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('MerchanCicle'),
        'width' => '150px',
        'index' => 'mcircle',
        ));
    $this->addColumn('show_me_local', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('Show Me Local'),
        'width' => '150px',
        'index' => 'show_me_local',
        ));
    $this->addColumn('superpages', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('Superpages'),
        'width' => '150px',
        'index' => 'superpages',
        ));
    $this->addColumn('topix', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('Topix'),
        'width' => '150px',
        'index' => 'topix',
        ));
    $this->addColumn('uscity', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('USCity'),
        'width' => '150px',
        'index' => 'uscity',
        ));
    $this->addColumn('where_to_app', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('Where To App'),
        'width' => '150px',
        'index' => 'where_to_app',
        ));
    $this->addColumn('yahoo', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('Yahoo'),
        'width' => '150px',
        'index' => 'yahoo',
        ));
    $this->addColumn('yellow_bot', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('YellowBot'),
        'width' => '150px',
        'index' => 'yellow_bot',
        ));
    $this->addColumn('yellow_wise', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('Yellowwise'),
        'width' => '150px',
        'index' => 'yellow_wise',
        ));            

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
```

}

And showing the edit form like the image attached not proper layout.
[image]

Please Look at the code and find out the mistake that i have made, why it is showing the blank form instead of values in it.

Comment: Show _registryObject function definition?

Comment: @Sohel Rana Here it is in my controller:
 protected function _registryObject()
    {

     $id=$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
     $data=Mage::getModel('optfirst_reviewmycompany/review')->load($id);
     Mage::register('optfirst_reviewmycompany', $data);
      }

Comment: @SohelRana I ve updated the question with registry object function

Comment: @Xabby check the values of this `echo $id=$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');` you are getting value of it?

Comment: @QaisarSatti  sure let me check it ...

Comment: @then check `$data=Mage::getModel('optfirst_reviewmycompany/review')->loa‌​d($id);  print_r($data);`

Comment: @QaisarSatti so how this registery function will be triggered? mean on which action ?

Comment: you are calling it in  **editAction** `public function editAction()

 {
     $this->_registryObject();`

Comment: Its giving me some strange array output @QaisarSatti

Comment: Actually i was using the wrong ID it was "id_optfirst_reviewmycompany" in my DB table i have updated it but still not working @QaisarSatti

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51511/discussion-between-xabby-and-qaisar-satti).

Comment: @QaisarSatti 
its give me the this output on printing the $id ..
Array ( [key] => de594e3b553d13c4bb1d0c9f17dc9143 )

Comment: if i gave it static $id = 1; it is showing values in form now..

Comment: @QaisarSatti why it is not printing the ID for this : echo $id=$this->getRequest()->getParam('id_optfirst_reviewmycompany');

Comment: then this is your grid problem share you grid code

Comment: @QaisarSatti Check the Form.php above in the question

Comment: @Xabby i am talking about where you calling the `editAction`

Comment: @QaisarSatti added the Grid.php in above question please check..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this function in your grid and check

```
public function getRowUrl($row)
  {
      return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id' => $row->getId()));
  }
```

Comment: Still printing the same : Array ( [key] => 69800f0ed12699da01a60f605385a683 )

I have added it after ->  return parent::_prepareColumns();

Comment: @Xabby use this for getting current id `echo $id=$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');`

Comment: But my primary_key is  id_optfirst_reviewmycompany in my DB table

Comment: Can u share your edit url?

Comment: Here it is: http://mxcounters.com/usa-tiles/index.php/admin/adminform/edit/key/744d1c8c0fac409e8f36b41c32e3803f/

Comment: Let me send it to you

Answer (score 0):

Okay. What if you change in `Form.php`:

```
$form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
        'id' => 'edit_form',
        'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/edit'),
        'method' => 'post',
        ));
```

to:

```
$form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
        'id' => 'edit_form',
        'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
        'method' => 'post',
        ));
```

if the form needs to be saved, then the `'action'` array element should be:

```
'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')))
```

Let me know if this helps